# I need to query information from two tables, using information connected through a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

This may be confusing, but basically what I have is the following tables:

`CREATE TABLE Employee(
eid int NOT NULL,
fname varchar(20),
lname varchar(20),
zip int,
PRIMARY KEY (eid));`

`CREATE TABLE Customer(
cid int NOT NULL,
fname varchar(20),
lname varchar(20),
street varchar(20),
city varchar(20),
zip int,
PRIMARY KEY (cid));`

`CREATE TABLE Orders(
oid int NOT NULL,
rdate date,
sdate date,
cid int NOT NULL,
eid int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (oid),
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customer(cid),
FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(eid));`

One of the questions for my assignment is the following:

> Create and execute a query that lists employee information together with the number or orders they have processed

Can someone help get me started? I literally don't even know where to begin...

`SELECT ???
FROM ???
WHERE ???`

Comment: You probably want to use an `INNER JOIN` or a `LEFT JOIN` by `SELECT`ing `Orders` and joining it with `Employee` on `eid`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      e.fname, e.lname, e.zip,
            OrdersProcessed = COUNT(o.oid)
FROM        Orders   o
INNER JOIN  Employee e ON o.eid = e.eid
GROUP BY    e.fname, e.lname, e.zip
```